# ¿Cómo frenar el código si un else se ejecuta?

Tags: python, else

Mi intención es  que, si el usuario que ingrese no es el que se registró anteriormente le lance que el usuario es incorrecto y se frene la ejecución del código.

```
Nombre = input("Ingrese un nombre de usuario a guardar")
Contra = input("Ingrese una contraseña a guardar")

print ("Su registro se realzó con éxito")
print ("Ahora deberá ingresar sus datos para confirmar su identidad")
print ("Ingrese su usuario")

if input() == Nombre:
    print ("Usuario correcto")
else: print("Usuario incorrecto")

print ("Ahora ingrese su contraseña")


if input() == Contra:
    print ("Contraseña correcta")
```

Comment: `sys.exit()` o `quit()` ?

Comment: En otros lenguajes existe el break; o también con un return para salir del metodo, no conozco python pero aveces las soluciones son iguales para todos los lenguajes.

Comment: Si lanzaste el script haciendo doble click sobre el `.py`, es normal. Cuando el programa python termina (ya sea con `quit()` o porque llega a su final), se cerrará la consola.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el quit me sirvió

Comment: como podría hacer para que en vez de terminar el programa le diera más intentos y pudiera seguir intentando su usuario?

Comment: @Isma crea un bucle while que verifique un booleano si sigue ejecutando esa logica o no.

Comment: Por favor JLDiaz colocalo en una respuesta para que Isma pueda colocarca como solución así le es útil a otros usuarios también que podrán ubicar rapidamente la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de abandonar la ejecución completamente, estés donde estés en tu programa, es invocar `quit()`, o si tienes cargado el módulo `sys`, invocando `sys.exit()`.

Respecto a la pregunta que haces en un comentario posterior acerca de un bucle de reintentos, el siguiente código muestra una posible forma de hacerlo.

```
print ("Ahora deberá ingresar sus datos para confirmar su identidad")

max_intentos = 3
intentos = 0
while intentos < max_intentos:
  quien = input("Ingrese su usuario")
  if quien == nombre:
    print("Usuario correcto")
    break
  else:
    print("Usuario incorrecto. Le quedan {} intentos".format(max_intentos - intentos -1))
  intentos = intentos + 1

if intentos == max_intentos:
  print("Lo siento, ya no puede intentarlo más")
  quit()
```

Tenemos un contador de intentos que se va incrementando cada vez que el usuario introduce el nombre mal. El bucle se repite mientras el contador esté por debajo de un valor dado. Si el usuario pone bien el nombre, se abandona el bucle mediante la instrucción `break`.

Una vez se ha salido del bucle, puede ser debido a que el usuario metió bien el nombre (y se ejecutó el `break` que interrumpió el bucle) o a que se alcanzó el máximo número de intentos (con lo que la condición del `while` deja de ser cierta y se sale de forma natural del bucle). La forma de distinguir cuál de los dos casos ha sucedido es examinar la variable `intentos` al salir del bucle. Si alcanzó el máximo se aborta la ejecucución.

Otro detalle para mejorar el código. Cuando pidas al usuario una contraseña, en lugar de `input()` conviene usar `getpass.getpass()` que oculta lo que el usuario escribe.